# drawing circle with radius specified in meters on a map

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet, mapbox

Any pointers on how to draw a circle of radius, specified in meters, on top of a geographical map using D3 would be pretty helpful.

I tried to use Leaflet and it's Circle(or CircleMarker) that accepts radius in meters, but I need more flexibility to play with my data. D3 seems to be pretty helpful, but am not sure how to draw a circle of given radius on top of a map, such the circle covers an area corresponding to the given radius (and adapts to zoom and change in projection).

Comment: "I need more flexibility to play with my data."  What do you want that leaflet can't do?

Comment: Are you talking about geodesic polygons? I do not think Leaflet supports this, not without some plugin. This post may offer some help: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17388/how-to-create-geodesic-polygons-in-openlayers . It's related to OpenLayers, but the logic could work here too.

Comment: In D3 you would have a geographic projection that tells it how to translate world coordinates into map coordinates. You can then use this to figure out the map radius of a circle at a specific position.

Comment: @PatrickD My data points are basically circles with radius specified in metres. I thought Leaflet's L.Circle supports this.

Comment: Leaflet's circle already do what you want. What's your problem?

Comment: @LSA problem is that I would need to vary the radius depending on other parameters dynamically. Hence, the need for D3. However, I'm not sure how I can go about using D3, here.

Comment: OK. So you don't care about geodesic circles. You care about dynamically changing the radius? How about using `L.Circle.setRadius()` whenever you need to do so?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can pass these radii in meters using the latest version of Leaflet. The radius will change relative to zoom levels.

Here's some more information via [Leaflet's documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#circle)

```
L.circle([lat,lng], radius).addTo(map);
```